# Format ISO 8601 date string to 0:00AM with javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging, date, iso8601, isodate

I have the following ISO 8601 date string:

```
var isoDate = 2013-10-01T09:00:00.000-04:00;
```

When attempting to format the date using the `Date()` function, the timezone of the date changes to my local timezone (note how it's `08:00` instead of `09:00`)

```
Date.fromISOString(isoDate);  /* Returns: Tue Oct 01 2013 08:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Standard Time)*/
```

I want to keep the **original timezone** of the current string completely in-tact.

If the string has `09:00`, I want to output `9PM`.

What is the most conventional way of doing this?

NOTE: I've also tried using [datejs](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) with no luck.  Trying the following returned a blank result:

```
Date.parse('2013-10-01T09:00:00.000-04:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `new` operator, the `Date` constructor, the `toISOString` method, and multiple string substitutions to preserve the original string:

```
var foo = "2013-10-01T09:00:00.000-04:00";
var bar = foo.substr(-6);
var baz = foo.substr(11,2)
var isoDate = new Date(foo).toISOString().replace("Z",bar).replace(/T../,"T"+baz);
var hours = String(baz).concat(Number(baz) < 12 ? "PM" : "AM").replace(/^0/,"")
```

**References**

- [Javascript convert timezone issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524065/1113772)